# Can't add navigation bar to scene: Root view controller issue?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xcode6

I'm still struggling with navigation bars and just can't work out how to edit or verify that I have a navigation bar on my view and I would appreciate any help.

I have a project with another set of scenes similarly comprising of a navigation controller and three associated view controllers (connected via segues and main table view embedded in the navigation controller) and I was able to add a navigation bar manually in interface builder to the outer view controllers that were segued to the table view controller.
*But in this set of scenes the navigation controller is set up as the root view controller for the table view.*

I have another set of scenes. A navigation controller and two related view controllers - both table view controllers. I embedded the first table view controller in the navigation controller and I then added a second table view controller to this (for a new screen I want to add to my app) and I connected this second table view controller to my first table view controller by way of a show segue (just like I did yesterday with other set of scenes).
*Can I set this other navigation controller as the root controller also?
Like, can I have two root view controllers in a project?*

It looks to me like there is a navigation bar visible (see screenshot below) on my new table view controller but I can't click in to it to edit it to add a title to it.
But does a navigation bar and exist, and if so, why can't I click inside it and use it?

I was told in an answer to a previous question that you have to add a navigation bar manually to your storyboard scene to any additional view controllers. I did that yday and it worked. But today when I tried to add a navigation bar by dragging onto scene it wouldn't let me do this.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding push segue(which is depreciated) and than change it to a show segue(between your tableviews). This is a workaround I use in my apps.

Comment: I've already added a show segue going from the first table view controller to the second table view controller.

Comment: What I am saying is delete it and than create a push segue between those two tableviews. After that change push segue to a show segue and try to excess navigation bar.(this is a workaround of a bug that I use.)

Comment: Are you sure it's not a root view controller issue? Seems strange that you would need to change nature of segues like that?

Comment: I looked up for this question for a week and I gave up. Did you tried my solution? If it works just use it for now.

Comment: I still have some time before I need to accept any solution and I'm holding out for a good fix. I appreciate your fix and I will try it, it just doesn't seem like it should be the best way. I know you realize that. Another way to do it is to embed the view in its own navigation controller but this too seems too much.

Comment: I am not saying that "please, give my answer an upvote", I am asking that if it is worked or not. I am using this kind of code in my project and I am curious about it. If you find better please feel free to post it here I'll do the same.

Comment: Shutting down and restarting Xcode worked for the task of just adding the navigation bar. But as seen from the screenshot, the bar had already been put in place by virtue of being connected to the navigation controller. I just wasn't able to see it in my document outline. I just added navigation items independently via object library.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. Had a good fallback position, I am doing a tutorial that came with example programs completed and working so the first thing I did was see if it was a version glitch between 6.3.2 and 6.4. Turned out the earlier project worked just fine.

So what I did was simply drag the 'Item' in the sidebar and moved it under the Root View Controller!

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue.

However, by saving and closing the project then reopening it, the Navigation Bar title is then able to be edited. Prior to closing/reopening the project the field could not be edited.